# Integrating AWS Pinpoint with Angular (for push notification)

Tags: javascript, angular, push-notification, aws-pinpoint

I need help. I want to use **Amazon Pinpoint** to be able to send notifications on PC. We already have an **AWS ID** and **key API**. My concern is the integration of this api with the **Angular** client and **pinpoint** using this ID and key. What tools should I install?  Or modules? Thank you

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/send-messages-push.html

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking-- you want to be able to use a client-side library to make calls directly to pinpoint?  I would advise against that: normally you would make those calls from a server/service that you control, protected by authentication and authorization.  Then the client code (Angular) calls your service.   But the is a [JS SDK for AWS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk).  And it has calls for pinpoint: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Pinpoint.html

Comment: I modified the topic, thanks for your help @MattMorgan